# Is this really a bad question?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing this question [Php check if a variable exists or just declaring it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991622/php-check-if-a-variable-exists-or-just-declaring-it) and I failed. I must say that I'm a bit surprised. Sure, it is a bit opinion based, but I still think it is a good (or at least decent) question.

Perhaps it is not 100% clear which option is best, but there are pros and cons with each method, and it is valuable to get an explanation of them.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the root of the question is:

> What would be the best approach...

The word "Best" is basically always subjective. Just like with any opinion, I can add facts to justify why I think a certain way is best, but at the end of the day, what I say is "best" is only my opinion, and someone else will have a different opinion and can find facts to back up what they say too.

On top of that, the question continues:

> What would be the best approach, given to code quality and readability?

Code quality and readability. Again, two more subjective measures. I've seen complaints here on Stack Overflow because one user edits another user's code to "improve readability" when really the user just prefers a different style which is equally readable. Code quality... That could be so many different things, maybe one person thinks the most important quality is efficiency, another thinks that the fewest number of bytes in the program is better quality, one user thinks that using magic numbers is of the devil because that code can't be easily changed and called code that uses them bad quality... You get the point. Subjective, and open to opinions.

The better question is simply to ask how to do it, or describe what is going wrong and what is expected. Then any correct answers will be valid even if there are several ways to do the same thing, and they won't be competing and contradicting about which answer is best and why.